# Overflow of absolute elements is not visible from dialog

Tags: html, css, dialog

I have a dialog with a fixed height. The **dialog** is scrollable to be able to view its overflowing content. However enabling: `overflow-y: auto`, cuts off the overflowing `position: absolute` **selector**.

How can I enable scrolling for overflowing content while simoultaneously being able to add overflowing absolute elements, that overflow outside of the **dialog**?

Or in other words: I want the black **selector** to reach outside of the **dialog** and maintain the **dialogs** scrollable content.

```css
.dialog_container {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  inset: 0;
}

.dialog {
  background: #ccc;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

.selector_container {
  position: relative;
}

.selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;;
  left: -50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog_container">
  <div class="dialog">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    <div class="selector_container">
      <div class="selector">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can achieve this by creating a **wrap to your dialog**.

#### Example:

#### [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-js-4jc8qh?file=/index.html:335-815)

```css
.dialog_container {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  inset: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.wrap-dialog {
  position: relative;
}

.dialog {
  background: #ccc;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

.selector_container {
  /*position: relative;*/
}

.selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
  <div class="dialog_container">
      <div class="wrap-dialog">
        <div class="dialog">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
            nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
            erat, sed diam voluptua.
          </p>
          <div class="selector_container">
            <div class="selector">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

However, be aware that will not work for all scenarios as tables or lists have to do it with cells. Actually, this is a **non-solved issue CSS**.

**Take a look at this post:** https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4092

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Unfortunately this isn't what I want. The selector should scroll with the content of the dialog

Comment: @FlorianLudewig Yep, I got it, seems that the first part was it but when the cursor is inside of black content, the scroll from parent is not moving. Thanks for the feedback.